# my Apple ID is ...@mac.com -- can I use it with iCloud?

Tags: mail.app, mobileme, icloud

When .Mac first came out I signed up for trial and got "myname"@mac.com

I never did subscribe to .Mac or MobileMe, but it appears I still "own" that email address because I just logged into iCloud with with "myname"@mac.com as my Apple ID.

Is there a way for me to use/send/receive mail with that email address?  When I try to set up iCloud/Mail with this email address it doesn't seem to take it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will not be able to use that email address as you do not actually own it. All email addresses are owned by Apple, it is reserved for your use at all times, but as you have not been using it it will not transfer. You will need to create a new email, as you can no longer subscribe to MobileMe.

Comment: This is correct, but if you like your reserved email, I would try to get it activated at http://appleid.apple.com and even reach out to apple support to see if there's anything that can be done other than waiting and hoping once mobile me goes away next June if that email could be "released" for your use again.

Answer (score 1):

According to apple's FAQ (you can find it here:http://www.apple.com/mobileme/transition.html)

> Can I keep my MobileMe email address once I move to iCloud? Yes. If
>   you have an active MobileMe account when you sign up for iCloud, you
>   can keep your me.com or mac.com email address and any email aliases
>   you have created and move your MobileMe mail, contacts, and calendars,
>   as well as your bookmarks, to the new service. When you're ready to
>   make the move, go to www.me.com/move.

You can try to move your emails to iCloud by visiting me.com/move

Comment: That FAQ is only for active MobileMe accounts. The OP said that he never subscribed to MobileMe, so it doesn't apply.